# Merge [g1] into [g1gc]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

Both refer to the hotspot G1 garbage collector.

In my opinion [g1gc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/g1gc) should be the canonical tag. While both are used in the wild it is more precise while still providing the same autosuggest.